# Cast NSDictionary as Dictionary in swift2

Tags: swift2

I am working through a tutorial that was written in swift2 - now I have swift2.1 installed. In Swift 2.1 the following cast throws an error

```
dictionaryOK = (dictionary as! NSDictionary as? Dictionary)!
```

The error is

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<Key,Value>' to type 'NSDictionary'
```

Can somebody help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solutuion is as follows:

```
dictionaryOK = (dictionary as! NSDictionary as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)!
```

Comment: why double cast? what type is dictionary?